# How to remove "No Password set" on my Django template for editing a profile

Tags: python, django

On my Django template when a user logs in and edits there profile I have this weird-looking message that reads **"No password set. Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this user's password, but you can change the password using this form."**
How can I prevent this from displaying on my template?
below is my code
**forms.py**

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    member_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Member Id'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='Firstname', required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Firstname'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Lastname', required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Lastname'}))
    email = forms.CharField(label='Email*', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Email'}))
    phone1 = forms.CharField(label='Phone Number 1*', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Phone Number 1'}))
    phone2 = forms.CharField(label='Phone Number 2', required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Phone Number 2'}))

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('member_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone1', 'phone2')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the password behaviour of the `UserChangeForm`, then I would subclass `forms.ModelForm` instead. If you look at the code for [`UserChangeForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9e2355eb07938829a1a31ed7b60e5f72d4b92e3/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L141) it isn't really doing anything else.

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    member_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Member Id'}))
    ...

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('member_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone1', 'phone2')
```

The important thing is that you are explicitly setting `fields`, so the `password` field will not appear in the form.

Answer (score 0):

This is form field help text

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(label=_("Password"),
        help_text=_("Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see "
                    "this user's password, but you can change the password "
                    "using <a href=\"password/\">this form</a>."))
```

You can [override default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) help text

```
 class Meta:
        help_texts = {
            'password ': _(''),
        }
```

Also it doesn't make much sense in your case to subclass UserChangeForm at all

Comment: Thanks for your response